# Error "The system administrator has set policies to prevent this installation", while implementing MSI package with perUser installation

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Right now am writing XML code, to create a MSI package using WIX toolset,
I have used InstallScope as perUser, also I am trying to copy a set of files to App Data local folder during the installation, So that no elevated privileges required.

Once I build the code in Visual Studio and double click the MSI file genenrated, it throws error as 
"The system administrator has set policies to prevent this installation", but perUser installation does not need any admin privileges. I do not know why I get this error

Please give me some solution

```
<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id='ProductComponents' Directory='INSTALLFOLDER'>
        <Component Id='test.bat'>
            <File Id='test.bat' Name='test.bat' Source='resources/test.bat' KeyPath='yes' />
        </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

MSI should run without admin privileges

Comment: Does it work on other machines?  What is the following registry key set to on that machine?
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer]
"DisableMSI"=dword:00000000

Comment: What does your Product element look like?